# Java extends error

Tags: java, android, class, nullpointerexception

I have three Java classes.

```
public abstract class ActivityDefault extends Activity {
    protected abstract int getActiveButton();
}


public abstract class ActivityToolsDefault extends ActivityDefault {
    public ToolStructure str;
    public ActivityToolsDefault(int id, boolean loadVars) {
        str = new ToolStructure(id, this, loadVars);
    }
}

public class TConcentracaoDioxido extends ActivityToolsDefault {
    public TConcentracaoDioxido() {
        super(1, true);
    }
}
```

And at "**super(1, true);**" I'm getting java.lang.NullPointerException.
I'm just showing the main of the classes, there are attributes and methods (not used yet).

Anyone know the reason?

Thanks so much!

Comment: My guess is that it's coming from inside the `ToolStructure` constructor. Please post the logcat output showing the stack trace.

Comment: @TedHopp, take a look: http://pastebin.com/ksV3Yyik

Comment: @TedHopp, you were right. ToolStructure  was the problem. I didn't figure out because the exception was on super(1, true);
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can't answer completely right now, but I suspect the problem is the unsafe publication from the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever you create an class with extending **Activity** you **must have to override some methods(atleast OnCreate)**. 
Also setContentView or Inflator to set a view for Activity is necessary.

Comment: Anil, I have this method. Just not wrote on the question because I think it's not the point. @Ted Hopp commented about the new ToolStructure. That was the problem. Thanks by the way!